# Unblur Windows 10 1903 login screen

Tags: windows, windows-10

I just updated a couple PCs from Windows 10 1803 to Windows 10 1903. I immediately noticed the login screen now has a blurred glass effect over the wallpaper.

Is there a way to turn this off?

Preferably via group policy. It looks ***really awful*** on the default wallpaper distributed in our AD domain. Other options are useful, too, but a Group Policy will win my green check accepted answer over another work-around.

Comment: Three ways to do it.....https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-disable-the-blur-effect-on-the-windows-10-login-screen/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Preferably via group policy. It looks really awful on the default wallpaper distributed in our AD domain. Other options are useful, too, but a Group Policy will win my green check accepted answer over another work-around.

It is absolutely possible to disable the transparent effect you describe.  In order to disable the transparent effect on the desktop background you must **Enable** the `Show Clear Logon Background` policy.

> 1. Navigate to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Logon.
> 2. Locate “Show clear logon background” in the right pane and double-click on it.
>
> [image]
>   3. Set the “Show Clear Logon Background” to “Enabled” and then click “OK.” You’ll have to restart your PC before the change takes effect.
>   [image]

Source: [How to Disable the Login Screen’s Background Blur on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/426554/how-to-disable-the-login-screens-background-blur-on-windows-10/)